# Bug, css: badges gets cut off on top

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The top of the badges gets cut off. This is clear on the gold badges, not so much on the other two:

[image]

Comment: in what browser and operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now fixed. The change will be on live after the next production build.

Comment: Sweet! And just to be clear: you have managed to make a bunch of ornery designers very happy. Well done!